# Angular Paths: get file from folder that is on the same directory level

Tags: angular, typescript, path

This must be very simple yet with multiple tries and a whole manner of constellations I am unable to get it right.

[image]

From the picture above, what is the correct path to import `is-desktop.service.ts` from the `_services` folder into `app.component.ts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./` means u are now in this directory. so u should  start with `./`

```
import {IDesktopService} from './_services/is-desktop.service'
```